# query not found for webpack custom loader

Tags: webpack

I am writing custom loader for one of my project. I was able to set up up loader which gets executed for extensions mentioned in test.
following is the code for webpack.config.js

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var lessLoader = ['css' , 'postcss-loader', 'less'];
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    context : __dirname,
    entry : [
        './entry.js',
        './app.less',
        './src/test.html',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:5114'
    ],
    debug : true,
    output : {
        path : __dirname + "/src/",
        publicPath : '/',
        filename : 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolveLoader : {
        alias : {
            "test-loader" : path.join(__dirname, "./loaders/test-loader")
        }
    },
    resolve : {
        // alias : require("./webpack-module-alias.js")
    },
    module : {
        loaders : [
            {
                test : /\.less$/,
                loader : ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', lessLoader.join('!'))
                // loader : "style!css!postcss-loader!less"
            },
            {
                test : /\.html?$/,
                loader : 'test-loader',
                query : {
                   config : "test"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins : [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("app.css")
    ],
    devServer : {
        contentBase : __dirname + '/src/'
    }
};
```

following is the code of custom loader

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(source) {
    console.log("Query " ,this);
    return JSON.stringify("");
};
```

I am expecting to receive the query parameter defined for loader in custom loader file. but instead I am just receiving empty query field like following.

> { data: undefined,
>     inputValue: undefined,
>     query: '',
>     async: [Function: async],
>     callback: [Function] } ''

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

It will be good If some one can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open bug to solve this [1289](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1289)

For now, remove your alias and do like add your load directly:

```
{
   test: /\.(woff2|woff|ttf|eot|svg|otf)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
   loaders: [
      __dirname +'/path/to/your/loader/your-loader?limit=1000000&name=assets/fonts/[name]_[hash].[ext]'
   ]
}
```